# (UndefinedFunctionError) function :ssl.cipher_suites/1 is undefined or private

Tags: ssl, erlang, elixir

I'm seeing this warning:

`(UndefinedFunctionError) function :ssl.cipher_suites/0 is undefined or private`

My application is crashing with this warning.

I recently upgraded Elixir and Erlang using `asdf`. How do I start my application now?

Comment: mix local.hex fixed my similar issue. https://elixirforum.com/t/keep-getting-the-error-function-ssl-cipher-suites-1-is-undefined-or-private/40043

Comment: https://kaferacer.medium.com/elixir-mix-function-ssl-cipher-suites-1-is-undefined-or-private-dfec4ddab428

Answer (score 1):

[This Erlang page](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:9bq_tglecwUJ:erlang.org/doc/general_info/deprecations.html+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=pt) says:

> Functions Deprecated in OTP 21
>
> - ssl:cipher_suites/0 (use cipher_suites/2,3 instead)
> - ssl:cipher_suites/1 (use cipher_suites/2,3 instead)

At the time of writing, the

I got it to work by changing the function call to:

`:ssl.cipher_suites(:all, :"tlsv1.3")`

Reference: [Erlang manual for `cipher_suites/23`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html#cipher_suites-2)